# why delete the checkpoint file after finish loading its stored offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

in kafka 0.10.2.0,when finished init the ProcessorStateManager,why delete the checkpoint file:

```
// load the checkpoint information
OffsetCheckpoint checkpoint = new OffsetCheckpoint(new File(this.baseDir, CHECKPOINT_FILE_NAME));
this.checkpointedOffsets = new HashMap<>(checkpoint.read());

// delete the checkpoint file after finish loading its stored offsets
checkpoint.delete();
```

if then I kill the application forcefully, and restart it, it will not load the checkpoint file because it is deleted, so when restoring the partition's state:

```
if (checkpointedOffsets.containsKey(storePartition)) {
    restoreConsumer.seek(storePartition, checkpointedOffsets.get(storePartition));
} else {
    restoreConsumer.seekToBeginning(singleton(storePartition));
}
```

as it will execute seekToBeginning, then the consumer will consume from offset 0.

Answer (score 0):

i find an answer:

[KAFKA-4317](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4317)

[PATCH](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/2471/files/291ff370a0bc714bcb4dda1b4fb98eb71e0d967f)